# Modify application wide, the display of DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, format, cultureinfo

For an application we develop, we use the `"G"` format everywhere in our application.

We want to change a little bit this format:

We need to display the first digit after the second.

Ex:

> 29.07.2014 08:54:36.1

We would like to be able to change this in the `CurrentCulture`.

It's the only thing we want to change in the current culture, so if before, we were having the following format:

> 2014/07/29 08:54:36 AM

We then want to have

> 2014/07/29 08:54:36.1 AM

If before I was having

> 29.07.2014 08:54:36

We then want to have

> 29.07.2014 08:54:36.1

A nice to have would be, that if the `DateTime` we receive, doesn't have a digit to be displayed here( =0 tenth of seconds), to don't have this displayed.

Comment: It might be useful to create a short concise example that demonstrates your current problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) for the current thread and specify a deviating [`LongTimePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();

change the culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "your pattern";

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Comment: Do you think I can just replace a part of the pattern? Like `ss` by ` `ss.f`

Comment: This should to it, yes.

Comment: @J4N: Any luck trying this out?

Comment: Hi, I've juste some jobs to finish to be able to receive data with this granularity, but here what I've done:
`Replace("ss", "ss" + currentCultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "F");`

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and looks like is returning what you are looking for except for the "nice to have".

```
string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.f tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Like I said, I only want to force to display this first digit, the other part(format of the date, ...) should not change. With this we will always have the EN-US format, what if we have another format(which doesn't have `/` separators? with a 24H display?)

Comment: @J4N, sorry I do not get your point. If you do not need the AM-PM then you can use another culture and take out the tt.

Comment: Our application is distributed worldwide. If an US user uses it, we want to have his format + display of tenth of seconds, if we have a german user, we want to have his format + display of tenth of seconds. With your proposal, the user will have the culture of another country in most case except for one country

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an extension method for DateTime, something like a ToPrettyPrintStringg() or whatever you wanna call it that returns the date in the format you wish, this way you can get it to display any date the way you want everywhere.