# Override DateTime serialization to string

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime, serialization

In my **WPF** app, I want to give the user the option to present all the dates in different time zones. That is, to keep the data as is but only present it differently in **TextBlock** Text Binding to **DateTime**.

I'm trying to achieve this **without introducing a wrapping type or else use converters** - this would be bad design as this could easily be missed by other developers who would be working on the code. Also, that way the existing code could be kept intact.

Is there a way to intervene in the **DateTime** serialization to string inside the **TextBlock** binding and insert my own logic there? using a custom serializer?

Or otherwise, is there a way for me to override the basic **DateTime.ToString()** Method and insert my own logic there?

Comment: set [`StringFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) against your `TextBlock.Text` binding

Comment: DateTime, Numbers etc formatted on the basis of CultureInfo, so you need to change only it.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to display other data not other format. same format, different time - according to time zone.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want :) If current date in one textblock and other in another, then you will need to create converter, or type of your own. CultureInfo as maximum can be different for separate threads.

Comment: @user3065661 check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009870/modify-application-wide-the-display-of-datetime) answer

Comment: As alternative you can try to create some TimeZoneBehaviour

Answer (score 0):

you can use converter in binding:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx
IValueConverter
 xaml:

```
 “Source =”{Binding MyDate, Converter={StaticResource MyDateTimeZoneConverter}}
```

and add Timezoneconversion logic into class MyDateTimeZoneConverter:IValueConverter{...}

Comment: Yes, of course. But as I said, this would cause two things: 1st, I would have to visit all the places in my app and edit them. 2nd, anyone coming to work on the code, might miss the need for time zone support. I need to manage it in one place, or at least at the least amount of places. Thanks.

Comment: you can set TimeZoneInfo.Local = Mytimezone; and DateTime.ToString() return string in  Mytimezone time. but it's wrong %) I think better to use converters...